# microsoft sql server datediff for multiple dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to find the length of time between 2 dates (datetime types) based on the unique ID.  For example, I have the following data:

```
ID                 CallID                         Starttime                   
1                  56                             2011-01-04 10:00:00.000
1                  67                             2011-03-20 12:20:00.000
1                  70                             2011-04-08 15:00:00.000
2                  57                             2011-01-14 11:00:00.000
2                  62                             2011-02-14 11:00:00.000
2                  64                             2011-02-15 11:00:00.000
2                  75                             2011-04-14 11:00:00.000
2                  78                             2011-05-14 11:00:00.000
```

I need to find the length of time for all the CallIDs for each ID based on the previous call date (starttime).  For example, I need the length of time for all the calls for ID 1 (CallID 67 - CallID 56  and CallID 70 - CallID 67, etc.).

I know I need a loop of some kind that would go through the IDs to find the CallIDs for that ID but do I also need a temporary table where I would organize the CallIDs?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the desired output for both ID 1 and 2 in a table format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way.

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT ID,
                CallID,
                Starttime,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Starttime) RN
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.CallID,
       t2.CallID,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, t1.Starttime, t2.Starttime)
FROM   T t1
       INNER JOIN T t2
         ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1
            AND t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: This looks great even though I can't get it to run (still learning!) for some reason...  I will continue to try to run it and check this answer.  Thanks also for editing for me!

Comment: I finally got this to work and it's beautiful. Thank you so much!